# Different results for logically same, but textually different queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Is there any reason why the following queries would return different results?

```
select count(id) 
from mytable 
where 
  status='active' 
  and ((textfield1 ilike '%needle%') or (textfield2 ilike '%needle%'));
```

vs

```
select count(id) 
from mytable 
where 
  status='active' 
  and ((textfield1 || textfield2) ilike '%needle%');
```

When I'm running these queries, the former is returning `26` and the latter `19`.

What idiotic mistake am I making?

Comment: `(('aaa' ilike '%ab%') or ('bbb' ilike '%ab%')) == false` and `(('aaa' || 'bbb') ilike '%ab%') == true`. Use something like `(textfield1 || CHAR(0) || textfield2)`.

Comment: Are you sure the 1st query returns more results that the 2nd? I would expect the opposite.

Comment: Those two queries are not doing the same thing

Comment: I triple-checked. The first query **is** returning more results than the second!

Comment: That could happen if there are nulls. If you use `SELECT textfield1, textfield2` instead of `SELECT count(id)`, you can see which rows differ between the 2 queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have null values? If yes, the second form will be evaluated as null.

For example:

```
NULL || 'needle' = NULL
```

This way the second form can have less values than first one.

Try this:

```
coalesce(textfield1 ,'') || coalesce(textfield2,'')
```

Comment: 100% absolutely correct. `NULL` strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reason is that the queries are not logically equivalent.

Just put `textfield1 = 'I need'` and  or `textfield2 = 'lemons'`.

Then `(textfield1 ilike '%needle%') or (textfield2 ilike '%needle%')` evaluates to `false`
but `textfield1 || textfield2 = 'I needlemons'`
so `(textfield1 || textfield2) ilike '%needle%'` evaluates to `true`.